Show that $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is measureable if a coordinate function $f_i$ is measureable

Let be $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ measureable spaces, $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$, where $f(x):=(f_1(x),\dotsc,f_n(x))$ and $f_1:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is measureable. Show that $f$ is also measureable.

(Actually, in the lecture it was asssumed that all $f_i$ must be measureable but I think that it suffices if only one of those $f_i$ is measureable)

My approach:
Lemma: We know from lecture that if $f^{-1}(C)\in\mathcal{A}$ for all $C\in\mathcal{C}$ then $f^{-1}(C)\in\mathcal{A}$ for all $C\in\sigma(\mathcal{C})$. (Here, $\mathcal{C}$ denotes a generator see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebras_generated_by_families_of_sets)
Also, we know that $\boxtimes_{i=1}^n\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a generator of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e. $\sigma\left(\boxtimes_{i=1}^n\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right)=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Next, we choose an arbitrary set $B=(B_1,\dotsc,B_n)\in\boxtimes_{i=1}^n\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and know that there exists a set $A\subseteq\Omega$ such that $f(A)=(f_1(A),\dotsc,f_n(A))=(B_1,\dotsc,B_n)=B$. As $f_1$ is measureable we know that $f^{-1}(B_1)=A\in\mathcal{A}$. As $B$ was chosen arbitrarily we know that each set of $\boxtimes_{i=1}^n\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ has a preimage in $\mathcal{A}$. So by applying the above mentioned lemma we know that $f$ is measureable.
Can I prove the statement this way? It feels a bit strange if I only assume $f_1$ to be measureable?!
Any feed back is welcome :)

This shouldn't be true without the assumption that all the coordinates are measurable. The map $(x_1,...,x_d)\mapsto x_i$ is measurable for all $i$. So if $f$ is measurable, it would imply that each coordinate of the function is measurable.

No way. All of them must be measurable. Consider $f_1$ constant function and $f_2$ non-measurable function.

Take $f_1=0$ and $f_2$ to be any non measurable function.

Some of your steps seem wrong to me. If $f(A)=B$, this does not mean that $f^{-1}(B)=A$. If I am not mistaken, the preimage of $B=\prod_{i=1}^n B_i$ under $(f_1,...,f_n)$ is $\cap_{i=1}^n f_i^{-1}(B_i)$.
This should make it clearer why you must have that each $f_i$ is measurable for $f$ to be measurable.

Ah ok, I see. If I had precisely written down the preimage I would have noticed it. It should be $$f^{-1}(B):={x\in\Omega\mid f(x)\in B}={x\in\Omega\mid f_1(x)\in B_1,f_2(x)\in B_2,\dotsc, f_n(x)\in B_n}.$$ So if $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ then it must satisfy all $n$-conditions of the set definition which means $x\in f_1^{-1}(B_1)\cap f_2^{-1}(B_2)\cap\dotsc \cap f_n^{-1}(B_n)$. Hence, $f^{-1}(B)=f_1^{-1}(B_1)\cap f_2^{-1}(B_2)\cap\dotsc \cap f_n^{-1}(B_n)$.  Is this correct?

Yes, that is what I meant.
